# desktop application system where i wants to backup the data base

Tags: java, mysql, swing, runtime, database-backups

I have created a desktop application system where I want to backup  the database.

I am using the code shown below:

```
 process p = null;
 p = runtime.exec("E:/xampp/mysql/bin/mysqldump -uroot --add-drop-database -B clinic_management -r "+path+".sql");

 int processComplite = p.waitFor();

 System.out.println("processComplite" + processComplite);

 if(processComplite==0) {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "<html><center> backup complite<br> Check this folder<br>"+path+"</center><html>");
      jTextField1.setText("");
 } else {
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " backup  not complite");
 }
```

It's working fine in some systems but sometimes it shows

```
 processComplite=1
```

Comment: please to read Oracle tutorials EventDispatchThread, epsecially part about SwingWorker, short explanations ---> all events for Swing APIs must be done on EDT and your code has a problem with showing the JOptionPane

Comment: @mKorbel You are missing the point. He doesn't understand that "complite" is not about being complete; but that return code from executing that dump call ... and that != 0 means. the dump failed.

Comment: @GhostCat I'm commented only EDT, :-) as aside MySQL has quite/very good designed JDBC API, then maybe there isn't reason to use (explanations of wrong idea) runtime.exec as an answer here

Answer (score 1):

See the javadoc for [waitFor()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor()):

*Returns: the exit value of the subprocess represented by this Process object. By convention, the value 0 indicates normal termination.*

In other words: your database operation is failing. There are two things you can do:

- Check if mysqldump generates log files; and see if you can find anything in there
- As of now, you are **completely** ignoring any output that would be written to stdout/stderr when making that process call.

Meaning: you can get access to messages *potentially* written by msqldump by doing something like:

```
 InputStream stdout = p.getInputStream();
 InputStream stderr  = p.getErrorStream();
 int returnCode = p.waitFor();
 if (returnCode == 0) {
   ... give positive message
 } else {
   read data from streams and display those
```